# Asymptotic lower bounding does not work. Why?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory, lower-bound

Ok so this is not a homework question obviously, but here is the thing:
The bubble sort algorithm is said to be O(n^2), Ω(n).
However, if we plot its time complexity as a graph (average case), and try to lower bound it, a more accurate lower bound would be Ω(n^2). However contextually we see that Ω(n) is correct. So why does lower bounding the algorithm's runtime does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up concepts:

1. Lower bound vs upper bound:   Ω(f(n)) is a lower bound, and O(f(n)) is an upper bound.
2. Best vs worst case:  Unless otherwise stated, both Ω(f(n)) and O(f(n)) refer to the worst case running time, as a function of the input size.

For bubble sort, the *worst* case input of size n is *guaranteed* to take quadratic time, so bubble sort is O(n<sup>2</sup>) and Ω(n<sup>2</sup>).

The reason "bubble sort is said to be Ω(n)" is that a *lot* of people mess this up.

Remember that Ω(f(n)) is the *set* of functions that are asymptotically bounded underneath by f(n), and when you see "Algorithm X is Ω(f(n))", read it "The worst case running time of Algorithm X *is in* Ω(f(n))".

(Note however that Dmitry's answer is also also correct.  Because omega is a lower bound, Ω(1), Ω(log n), Ω(n), Ω(n log n), and Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) all apply)

Comment: I would argue you are one of the people who "mess this up", by your own words. "bubble sort is Ω(n2)." is wrong, since there exist inputs on which bubble sort takes n operations only.

Comment: Additionally, the op explicitly said "if we plot its time complexity as a graph (average case)" but your answer only mentions "best vs worst", not "average".

Comment: Well, @Stef, you argue incorrectly.  As I said, unless otherwise stated, the bound is usually applied to the worst case... but the average case time for bubble sort is also in Ω(n^2)

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it might be worth mentioning that bubble sort is also in Ω(n), just as it is in Ω(1) and O(n**100).

Comment: "unless otherwise stated, the bound is usually applied to the worst case" This is wrong by definition. A lower bound is a lower bound. The mathematical statements you write have precise definitions. You can't say "all boats sink" and then say "the statement 'all boats sink' is usually applied to the worst case of boats". "The worst-case running time of bubble sort is Ω(n^2)" and "the running time of bubble sort is Ω(n^2)" are two different statements, and one of them is false.

Comment: So does this mean that lower bound and upper bound are not the worst and best cases? I have seen many times that Ω is used to denote the best case, and the lower  bound. So when people say that an algorithms best case runtime is Ω(f(x)), does this mean that the lower bound of the best case is f(x), or does it refer to the exact bound or upper bound of best case? same thing for the worst case. I do not get it.

Comment: @GameOver If the best case is Ω(f(x)), then there is no input for which the algorithm is asymptotically faster than f(x). If you just say "the algorithm is in Ω(f(x))", then usually worst case is implied, and it means that worst case, the algorithm is not faster than f(x).

Comment: @GameOver To summarize, the choice between O, Ω and Θ indicates whether we talk about an upper bound, lower bound, or strict bound of some function (in this case the runtime of an algorithm as a function of the size of the input). This is separate from worst case, average case and best case. To be completely precise, you have to make clear which case you're studying, but in practice the average and worst case are often asymptotically the same, and the best case is entirely uninteresting, so the convention is that we consider worst case unless otherwise specified.

Comment: So many here tell me that Ω and best case are 2 different things, Ω being just the lower bound, with which we can describe the best case, however we can also say that best case is O(f(n)) which will refer to the upper bound of the best case. this seems to make sense. Does this mean that we can describe any case as O, Ω, or Θ? (Just in cs50, a computer science that i took, they always described best case as Ω and worst case as O, that might be where i go the confusion)

Comment: @GameOver lots of people make this mistake, some because they are actually mistaken, and some because they don't really care about the intricacies. It's entirely possible that a course instructor would give the incorrect definition. To answer your question, you can indeed study best and average and worst and typical cases for each of O, Ω and Θ. For example, best case for bubble sort is in Θ(n), and therefore also in Ω(n) and O(n). Similarly, worst and average case are in Θ(n\*\*2), and therefore also in Ω(n\*\*2) and O(n\*\*2).

Comment: @Stef the running time of bubble sort in general is *not* a function of the input size.  That's why when you refer to it as a function, for example by saying it's in a set of functions like Ω(n^2), the reader has to assume that you mean best, worst, average case, or something else that *is* a function of the input size.    The statement "the running time of bubble sort is Ω(n^2)" is not false. It's ambiguous, and the ambiguity is resolved by the usual assumption that the worst case is being referred to.

Answer (score 1):

Ω(n) by definition is lower bound and does not have to be tight. It just guarantees that algorithm works not better than linearly.

Ω(1), Ω(log(n)) are also valid lower bounds for bubble sort execution time. Not very informative, but still valid.

Answer (score -1):

The following statements are all true:

- For every number n, Bubble Sort never performs more than n(n-1)/2 comparisons and n(n-1)/2 swaps on a list of length n
- For every number n, there exists a list of length n on which bubble sort performs exactly n(n-1)/2 comparisons and n(n-1)/2 swaps (example: a list sorted in reverse order)
- For every number n, Bubble sort never performs fewer than (n-1) comparisons on a list of length n
- For every number n, there exists a list of length n on which bubble sorts performs exactly (n-1) comparisons and 0 swaps (example: a sorted list)
- For every number n, if we take the list [1,2,...,n] and shuffle it uniformly at random, then the expected number of swaps of bubble sort is n(n-1)/4 (explanation: [this answer on CS.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29))

**Conclusion:** if we forget about the multiplicative constants, the worst-case running time is n^2, the best-case running time of bubble sort is n, and the average running time is n^2.

Note that "the average running time" is always a little ambiguous. I stated it differently in my last bullet point to remove the ambiguity. If your random lists follow a different probability distribution, then you will get a different result. In particular, bubble sort will need fewer swaps (and maybe fewer comparisons) on a list that has lots of duplicate elements. But if you don't care about the exact multiplicative constant, then most "reasonable" ways to generate "random lists" will lead to an expected complexity of n^2.

Now, your question might become: **Why is the expected running time of bubble sort so close to its worst-case running time, and so far from its best-case running time?**

The answer to this question is: the immense majority of permutations are "reasonably well shuffled", and only a small number of permutations are "almost sorted". In other words, if you shuffle a list at random, then the result will "look random". If you shuffle a deck of cards, the probability that you will accidentally sort the cards is very low.

The question is also a bit deceptive: the worst-case number of comparisons is n^2/2; the expected number of comparisons is n^2/4; the best-case number of comparisons is n-1. So actually, **the expected number of comparisons is almost exactly half-way between the worst case and the best case**.

The answer on CS.stackexchange is also a good explanation: of all pairs of elements in the list, we expect half the pairs to be in their relative order, and half the pairs to be in reverse relative order. So the expected running time is exactly half of the worst-case running time.